# Como puedo poner fin de mapa unity flappy bird?

Tags: unity

Teniendo estos scripts

**Bird**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Bird : MonoBehaviour {
    // Movement speed
    public float speed = 1;

    // Flap force
    public float force = 100;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // Fly towards the right
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.right * speed;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // Flap
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * force);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        // Restart
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }
}
```

**CameraFollow**

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {
    // The Target
    public Transform target;

    void LateUpdate () {
        transform.position = new Vector3(target.position.x,
                                         transform.position.y,
                                         transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

**Obstacle**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Obstacle : MonoBehaviour {
    // Movement Speed (0 means don't move)
    public float speed = 0;

    // Switch Movement Direction every x seconds
    public float switchTime = 2;

    void Start() {
        // Initial Movement Direction
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.up * speed;

        // Switch every few seconds
        InvokeRepeating("Switch", 0, switchTime);
    }

    void Switch() {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity *= -1;
    }
}
```

Como puedo poner fin de mapa?, creaty empty y inserto box collider 2d, y después como introduzco por script que si Bird llega a ese punto gane la partida, supongo que sea como

```
 void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        // Restart
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }
```

pero referenciado al objeto en cuestión

**Nuevo Bird con final en tiempo, gracias a la primera respuesta**

error en   t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed; Assets/Scripts/Bird.cs(21,8): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `t'

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Timers;
public class Bird : MonoBehaviour {
    // Movement speed
    public float speed = 1;


    // Flap force
    public float force = 100;

    public double Interval = 10000;

    private Timer t;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // Fly towards the right
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.right * speed;
        t = new Timer(Interval)
        t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;
        t.Start();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // Flap
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * force);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        // Restart
        t.Stop();
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }

    private static void T_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            t.Stop();
            ///
            /// aqui pones el codigo para mostrar que gano
            ///
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ni siquiera necesitas algo tan complicado, ya que el pájaro avanza hacia adelante a velocidad constante podrías simplemente poner un timer, si el jugador no ha muerto para cuando termine de contar el timer le muestras que ha ganado.

```
public class Bird : MonoBehaviour {
    // Movement speed
    public float speed = 1;


    // Flap force
    public float force = 100;

    public double Interval = 10000;

    private Timer t;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // Fly towards the right
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.right * speed;
        t = new Timer(Interval)
        t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;
        t.Start();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // Flap
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * force);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        // Restart
        t.Stop();
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }

    private static void T_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            t.Stop();
            ///
            /// aqui pones el codigo para mostrar que gano
            /// 
        }
}
```

Comment: Como podría hacer eso?

Comment: ahi actualice la respuesta

Comment: el intervalo esta en milisegundos, asi que si quires que gane en 5 segundos, le pones 5 mil (si te fijas ahora tiene 10 mil, asi que  ganara en 10 segundos

Comment: Muchas gracias colega :D

Comment: Si me permites la última pregunta, como puedo poner ese código para mostrar que ganó?

Comment: Al compilarlo me pone lo siguiente " Assets/Scripts/Bird.cs(18,8): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `t' "

Comment: arriba donde estan los using, ponle uno mas: using System.Timers

Comment: pongo " using System.Timers; " pero igualmente :( . Actualizo la primera página de stackoverflow?

Comment: estas seguro de que declaraste la variable t?

Comment: Si, he copiado y pegado en al primera pregunta, todo el código, y me sigue dando el error "  Assets/Scripts/Bird.cs(21,8): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `t'
" parece que es en "  t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;"

Comment: sabes por que podría ser?